# Error cannot resolve module "crypto" when creating wallet address

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, wavesplatform

I am trying to create a wallet to hold a newly created coin on the waves platform.

Metro Bundler has encountered an internal error, please check your terminal error output for more details
While trying to resolve module `crypto` from file `C:\Users\El\.expo\bandzWallet\node_modules\@waves\waves-crypto\random.js`, the package `C:\Users\El\.expo\bandzWallet\node_modules\crypto\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`C:\Users\El\.expo\bandzWallet\node_modules\crypto\index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

- `C:\Users\El\.expo\bandzWallet\node_modules\crypto\index.js(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
- `C:\Users\El\.expo\bandzWallet\node_modules\crypto\index.js\index(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
  Failed building JavaScript bundle.
  Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

  "use strict";
  Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
  const random = (count) => {
      if (isBrowser) {
          const arr = new Uint8Array(count);
          const crypto = (global.crypto || global.msCrypto);
          crypto.getRandomValues(arr);
          return arr;
      }
      const crypto = require('crypto');
      return Uint8Array.from(crypto.randomBytes(count));
  };
  const ensureBuffer = () => {
      try {
          const b = new Buffer(1);
      }
      catch (e) {
          throw new Error('Buffer not supported in this environment. Use Node.js or Browserify for browser support.');
      }
  };
  const isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined' && ({}).toString.call(window) === '[object Window]';
  exports.secureRandom = (count, type) => {
      switch (type) {
          case 'Array8':
              return Array.from(random(count));
          case 'Array16':
              return Array.from(exports.secureRandom(count, 'Uint16Array'));
          case 'Array32':
              return Array.from(exports.secureRandom(count, 'Uint32Array'));
          case 'Buffer':
              ensureBuffer();
              return Buffer.from(random(count));
          case 'Uint8Array':
              return random(count);
          case 'Uint16Array':
              return new Uint16Array(count)
                  .map(_ => random(2).reduce((a, b, i) => a | b << 8 * (1 - i), 0));
          case 'Uint32Array':
              return new Uint32Array(count)
                  .map(_ => random(4).reduce((a, b, i) => a | b << 8 * (1 - i), 0));
          default:
              throw new Error(type + ' is unsupported.');
      }
  };
  //# sourceMappingURL=random.js.map

i am trying to use @waves/waves-crypto to create a wallet adderss and seed on the testnet.

I am using React Native and Expo cli